# Question on the existence of biproduct. Am I correct?

Tags: category-theory

I am not much familiar with category theory language. I saw this on Wikipedia:
[image]

I suppose $f$ comes from this:

[image]

Where by $p_1\times 0$ I mean the morphism that makes this commutative:

[image]

Then, that $f$ is an isomorphism guarantees $A\coprod B$ is both a product and a coproduct. Also, denoting $r_i=p_i\circ f$, since $p_1\circ(p_1\times 0)=\text{id}_A$ and $p_2\circ (p_1\times 0)=0$, and $f\circ i_1=p_1\times 0$, that $r_1\circ i_1=1_A$ and $r_2\circ i_1=0$ follows.

Am I right about this?

Comment: Looks good to me